# Some question about the statement of Zorn Lemma

Tags: set-theory

Some textbooks describe the Zorn Lemma as: Every nonempty ordered set S has the maximal element if every totally ordered subset of S has an upper bound in S. Some other books replace the upper bound with maximal element which requires that the maximal element belongs to the totally ordered subset of S.

Are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: I do not think the second statement is correct. However, I am not able to get to a counterexample.

Comment: The second statement is implied by Zorn's lemma, so it is not false. But I do not think that the two are equivalent: you can apply the weaker version only to posets whose all chains have a maximum which is very restrictive.

Comment: Another comment about the statement: the conclusion of the Zorn's lemma is that there exists A maximal element for $S$, not "the" maximal element. Uniqueness is usually false: is like requiring the existence of a unique maximal basis for every vector space.

Comment: @ChushanWang; Can you give a reference to a book which uses the second form?

Comment: Thanks, all! The second statement is not equivalent ot the Zorn Lemma. The book uses the second statement is in Chinese, so some notions may be ambiguious due to the translation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the latter condition is strictly stronger. For example, consider the set $[0, 1]$ ordered by the usual ordering on the reals. Note that $[0, 1]$ has a maximal element $1$ (in fact, the maximum), so indeed every totally ordered subset has $1$ as an upper bound. However, not every totally ordered subset has a maximum. In particular, $(0, 1)$ has no maximum.

Answer (score 4):

The version where you require that every chain has a *maximum* is not the same as the usual Zorn's lemma.
It is equivalent to the [axiom of dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) which is rather weaker than the full axiom of choice.

To show this, consider it in contraposed form: If a partial order has no maximal element, then it contains a chain without a maximal element.

This is implied directly by the axiom of dependent choice, because we can start at any element and then keep choosing a larger element. The set of elements we choose is a chain without a maximum element.

On the other hand, we can prove DC from the weakened Zorn's lemma: Suppose we have a graph where every node has an outgoing edge. Pick a fixed node to start at and consider the partial order of finite paths that start at this node, ordered by the "is a prefix of" relation. This order has no maximal element (every such path can be extended), so by the weakened lemma it has a *chain* that has no maximal element. The *union* of that chain must be a ray in the graph, exactly what DC wants to exist.

Comment: You are not mistaken.